# I would like to store images of users in the server. (Android)

Tags: android, imageview, localhost

I would like to have the user's name and a picture. But I cannot find a way to upload it on a table in mysql, so I guess that it is not good for the size.
I found that is it good to store it in localhost. So it wouldn't be in a table, but in the localhost. 
I am using php my admin, is there any simple way or tutorial to store it?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to upload images to server running on localhost ,in order
to save an image in database table you have to use blob type if you are using mysql for example.
there are many tutorial available try this :
http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is around this is to convert your image base64 format then save in in mysql. You can upload the image to server > let server do conversion, then save to mysql.

See Here http://davidwalsh.name/data-uri-php

courtesy of David Walsh, the owner of the site above:

```
// A few settings
$image = 'cricci.jpg';

// Read image path, convert to base64 encoding
$imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($image));

// Format the image SRC:  data:{mime};base64,{data};
$src = 'data: '.mime_content_type($image).';base64,'.$imageData;

// Echo out a sample image
echo '<img src="',$src,'">';
```